# Can DVI to VGA conversion cause (noticeable) quality loss?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display

I have recently upgraded to Sapphire HD 5670 from onboard Nvidia GeForce 6150. My moitor has VGA and DVI. It's resolution is 1360X768. The graphics card has DVI, HDMi and fast port. Here is my setup:

1. I'm connecting DVI to VGA converter on DVI port of graphics card.
2. Then VGA cable from converter to VGA port of my LCD monitor

I'm seeing seeing blurry light red ouline aroud text and Crysis is very blurry at native resolution of 1360x768. here is a zoomed screen shot:
[image]

Can conversion of signals cause quality loss ?

Comment: If your issue shows up in a screenshot, it can't be caused by whatever output you're using.

Answer (score 1):

It can, but in most cases isn't that noticeable.

If your graphics card has DVI and your monitor has DVI, why aren't you running a DVI cable?

Comment: Also as a side note. Your screen shot looks fine. A screen shot takes an image of what it's outputting to the screen so won't always reflect what you actually see on the screen. This often comes up when people have their video cable slightly off kilter and then try to capture the green or blue screen they can see.

Comment: I don't have DVI cable but I will buy one and report here. I was thinking that signal conversion does not cause problems at this low resolution. Also I transferred the screen shot to my phone and noticed the same problem. Does this means that my graphics card is producing this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The red you see is the result of ClearType.

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/WhatIsClearType.mspx

Comment: Turning off ClearType doesn't solve the problem. I was using ClearType previously so this can't be a problem.

Comment: It may not be ClearType but it does look like some kind of sub-pixel font hinting - is it something Chrome is doing?

Comment: It's not Chrome.  Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting the "auto-sync" button on your monitor. Because VGA signal is analog, the monitor has to analyze the signal and try to figure where pixel rows start and ends. Auto-sync re-does this calibration.

The colors can also be results of sub-pixel anti-aliasing done by the desktop environment of your operating system. Those can usually be configured or turned off.

Comment: Neither auto-sync solved the problem nor turning off the ClearType.

Comment: Keep in mind, applications can override your Cleartype settings.